# How to trigger useEffect from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to trigger `useEffect` which is present in User component from the `AddUser` component.

In `Adduse`r component it adds the user data to API and in user component it fetches the API:

```
   return (
    <div>
      <ToastContainer position="bottom-center" />
      {addUserShown && <AddUser onHideAddUser={closeAddUser} />}
      <Header
        onShowAddUser={toggleAddUser}
        onSearchOnSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}
      />
      <Users searchPostData={searchPostData} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Is your useEffect triggered from a statet? Have you tried passing the setState function into the AddUser component and call it from inside there?

Comment: how can i pass the setstate fun inside adduser
both are rendered at the root

Comment: pass it as a prop like  how you are passing `onHideAddUser`?

Comment: should i pass the setstate present in the User component to the adduser component?
and what should i set the state to?
it will be duplicate code to again fetch the api in adduser component and set the state

Comment: You can define a function in the parent component that calls the API and sets the state, and pass this function into `AddUser`. When called from `AddUser`, it will do the API call and set the state, triggering your useEffect in the other child component.

Comment: so i should bring the api call logic from user component to the parent component where the both components are rendered 
and pass the state data to user component  and setstate to the add user component
is this what you are saying?

Comment: Based on my limited understanding of your question and context, yes. In fact, that might even save you from having to rely on useEffect.

Comment: thank you it worked 
but i have doubt  if there is a big application triggering root useeffect is not good right? because it will render the entire ui instead of only 1 list

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can consider using useContext which will only re-render the consumers instead of the root (in this case the Users component)

Answer (score 3):

```
const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {    
    fetchData();
  }, [
    reload
  ]);

return <ChildComponent setReload={setReload} />

// then on child component
<button onClick={()=>setReload(prev=>!prev)}>
```